# Finding object in a List(Of ...) by Name

Tags: vb.net, list, class

Okay, so this is probably a bit of a simple/silly question but help is greatly appreciated.

Right now, I'm adding classes to a list by going:

```
    Public RacersArray As New List(Of Racer)
    ...
    Dim tempRacer As New Racer()
    With tempRacer                 'create data that is to be 'add' or 'edit'
        .Name = InpName.Text
        .CleatSize = InpCleatSize.Text
        .SkillLevel = InpSkillLevel.Text
        .Height = InpHeight.Text
        .Team = InpPreferredTeam.Text
    End With
    RacersArray.Add(tempRacer)
```

I'm trying to reference items in this list by doing something like:

```
RacersArray.IndexOf(<Name>)
```

But obviously that won't work if they've all got the same item name 'tempRacer'.

I'm getting the strong feeling that this isn't how I'm meant to be doing this.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Put them in a dictionary... Also if they all have the same name, what distinguishes them? You need a key for each object you add so you can find anyone you are looking for.

Comment: Instead of a list, try using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest is to add a `Shared` function to the `Racer` class. (You could use a `Predicate` to support the built-in `List(Of ).Find` method, but it is more complicated)

```
Sub Demo()
  Dim RacersArray As New List(Of Racer)
  RacersArray.Add(New Racer With {.Name = "Alpha", .CleatSize = "1", .SkillLevel = "Novice", .Height = "180", .Team = "Bananas"})
  RacersArray.Add(New Racer With {.Name = "Beta", .CleatSize = "2", .SkillLevel = "Journeyman", .Height = "160", .Team = "Apples"})
  RacersArray.Add(New Racer With {.Name = "Gamma", .CleatSize = "3", .SkillLevel = "Expert", .Height = "200", .Team = "Apples"})
  RacersArray.Add(New Racer With {.Name = "Delta", .CleatSize = "4", .SkillLevel = "Expert", .Height = "1950", .Team = "Bananas"})   
  Dim rcrFind As Racer = Racer.FindName(RacersArray, "Beta")
  If rcrFind Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Not found")
  Else
    MsgBox(rcrFind.Team)
  End If
End Sub

Class Racer
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property CleatSize As String
  Public Property SkillLevel As String
  Public Property Height As String
  Public Property Team As String

  Public Shared Function FindName(l As List(Of Racer), name As String) As Racer
    For Each r As Racer In l
      If r.Name = name Then Return r
    Next r
    Return Nothing
  End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access them through iteration.

```
For Each r As Racer In RacersArray
   'Access properties here..
    MessageBox(r.SkillLevel & " " & r.Team)
Next r
```

EDIT: if you want a specific name then

```
For Each r As Racer In RacersArray
    If r.Name = "Desired Name" Then
       'Access properties here..
        MessageBox(r.SkillLevel & " " & r.Team)
        Exit For
    End If
Next r
```

As a function

```
Private Function GetRacer(Byval RacersArray As List(Of Racer), Byval Name As String) As Racer
    Dim racerInfo As Racer
    For Each r As Racer In RacersArray
        If r.Name = Name Then
            racerInfo = r
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
    Return racerInfo
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

using simple for loop:

```
for i as integer =0 to RacersArray.Count -1
    'use RacersArray(i) to access item
next
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ...

```
Matches = (From r In RacersArray Where r.Name = "{name you're looking for}")
```

Matches will contain zero or more Racers with the name you specify.

You can get more specific by adding additional properties to the expression like this.

```
Matches = (From r In RacersArray Where r.Name = "Some Name" And r.Team = "Some Team")
```

I agree with Zaggler, you may want to consider adding a identifying property, or key, to ensure each Racer is unique.

Also, I suggest you drop "Array" in any list name.  "Racers" would be sufficient to know than it implies more that one.